# py3compile error - Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: linux, python

After reinstalled the python3.2, I got the error as below when call `py3compile`:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
Aborted
```

I know it may be the problem of missing environment variable. But I have no idea of how to fix it. I checked the `env`  output and didn't find any PYTHONXXX variables.

Answer (score 1):

Mind that this is a late response, since someone has offered a bounty on this question. Also note that without reproducing this problem I can't verify if any solution works. I will just suggest a solution here, not provide one.

I think you have to set two variables as outlined [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/1bjALmzZjwEXmLSOY7au#PyUeqcAsz4uwUdy), because `py3compile` needs to know where certain resources are. It looks them up via these PYTHONXXX variables.

So

```
export PYTHONPATH='/usr/lib64/python3.21:/usr/lib64/python3.2/lib-dynload:/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages'
export PYTHONHOME='/usr/lib64/python3.2'
```

or rather

```
export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/pythondir:/path/to/pythondir/lib-dynload:/path/to/pythondir/site-packages'
export PYTHONHOME='/path/to/pythondir'
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try following (replace opkg with your favorite package manager)

```
 # opkg install python3-modules
 # opkg install python3-misc
```

Comment: Not all package managers use directives like `install`. And, not all distros provide those packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here on voidlinux fixed this error by in addition to setting `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` relinking the symbolic link for the default python in `/usr/bin` from `python3.5` to `python2.7` for which I knew it was the one I set the paths for and which the program that requires python requires.

Note that setting the paths for `3.5` did not fix the `python3.5` `Py_Initialize` error here.
Who said maintaining systems is easy.

Which is why we have [0install](http://0install.net). If only it could be adopted by our open source world folks more. Currently we are struggling getting it to compile on voidlinux due to a libcurl OCaml issue. Most distributions have it in their package management repositories.

0install solves all these problems by fully encapsulating a program to have it run with the dependencies it requires without conflicting other version installed on the system or using 0install and saves package maintainers time because it eliminates those links inbetween the user system and the developers because the developers provide one 0install package for all systems directly (zero install is a `cross platform package management system`).